# Python multiple installations and Ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I try to run IPython from my shell

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~$ ipython --pylab
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

I want to double-check

```
conda install matplotlib
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/milenko/miniconda2:
#
matplotlib                1.5.1               np111py27_0 

conda update ipython
Fetching package metadata .......
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/milenko/miniconda2:
#
ipython                   4.2.0                    py27_0
```

How should I run Ipython using my conda package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're on linux.  Assuming you are using bash, open /home/milenko/.bashrc and make sure that /home/milenko/miniconda2/...python.exe (where that is the full path to your python executable) is at the beginning of your path.  Otherwise, calling ipython is probably opening a different python environment, which is very typical on linux.

Your bash profile (.bashrc) should have this line somewhere:

```
export PATH="/home/milenko/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

also you need to make sure that everything is installed for the environment you are running:

```
conda install jupyter
```

will install the ipython kernels and jupyter interfaces to run things inside the anaconda distribution.  If you did

```
sudo apt-get install jupyter
```

it will install it for your system python, not your anaconda python.

Comment: My path in bashrcexport PATH="/home/milenko/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"

Comment: as a quick check, what happens if you just call python, instead of ipython and then import matplotlib.  If this works, then your miniconda python is correctly in the path, but the ipython script is not

Comment: I can import matplotlib from my python script,no problem with this!

Comment: have you run conda install jupyter.  Looking at my linux bin directory, ipython is there.  It may be that you installed ipython through your linux package manager, so you have it for your distro, but that you did not install it for your miniconda distribution.

Comment: great, I updated my answer to reflect the necessary details